# How do I create a database that can contain an key value pair in a table columns?

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, api

I’m working on a project and I need to build an API, that I will have to call on the front end.

In the API, there’s need to have some values that are arrays in it and also values with key value pairs as in JavaScript Objects.

For example!
A table that will have many columns and some of the columns will be an arrays and some can be key value pairs.

Please how can I achieve something like that and also how to select it, I’m thinking of using PostgreSQL to create the database.

I know I can create different tables and use relationship to put them together but is not efficient for me! I want to be able to get everything on the table with one API call.

Comment: You could store the data in JSON column(s)

Comment: Please can you tell me more about it! I don’t know anything about it yet! I’m grateful for your response.

Comment: Assuming you know the basics of reading from and writing to a database table, read this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-json.html

Comment: Amazing enough Postgres has documentation [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html) and in those docs [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html).

Comment: You can also use `JOIN` to get data from multiple tables at one time.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I really appreciate you responds and I learned something from them.